# Having trouble creating user with supabase.auth.admin.createUser() method with error message "Database error creating new user"

Tags: typescript, next.js, supabase, supabase-js

I'm trying to create a user with supabase.auth.admin.createUser() method in my Next.js project, but it fails with error

```
{
   message: "Database error creating new user"
   name: "AuthApiError",
   status: 500,
}
```

My code is:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabaseAdmin.auth.admin.createUser({
        email: email,
        password: password,
        user_metadata: {
          nickname: nickname,
          introduce: introduce,
        },
      });
```

I've checked that email, password, nickname, introduce variables have correct values and types.
I've also checked I'm using correct supabase instance with correct supabaseUrl and supabaseServiceRoleKey.

I'm wondering if I can get more specific error message instead of "Database error creating new user", or I want to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: You can find more specific error messages on the error log from your Supabase dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and response from the server trying to do this using the python library as well. What fixed it for me was removing a trigger and function that ran on user creation that was having an issue. Luckily for me it was unneeded but I would check your triggers and functions for the auth schema and see if there's anything there causing the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).